# converting a string to bits in ruby, adding 1 bit and converting back to ascii

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bit-manipulation, bit

I am writing a ruby uid generator and i need to generate unique ids in incremental order. The unique ids are strings that vary from 3 to 9 characters.

What i want to achieve is this:

Get the last generated identifier, convert it to bits, and 1 bit to it(basically do a + 1) and convert the result back to ascii. This way i can prevent a unique id from being generated twice.

How can i do this in ruby. I am aware of #pack and #unpack methods but i can't figure out a way.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
a = "Foobar".unpack("B*")[0].to_i(2)+1
```

=> 77444424032627

```
["0" + a.to_s(2)].pack("B*")
```

=> "Foobas"

Comment: that's equivalent to `"Foobar".succ`

Comment: So what I need is this: I have a set of characters [0-9A-Z], su numbers and only uppercase letters. I want to be able to start from 000 and go up to ZZZZZZZZZ(9 Zs) just by changing the last bit without  choosing randomly. Is that possible in ruby?

Comment: Do you want all the permutations? Use then: a = (0..9).to_a + ("A".."Z").to_a a.permutation(3).to_a

Comment: Or if you want a function that based on a uid then generates the successor uid, then you should use succ and some logic in your function for detecting changes for numbers and chars. Explore this code: a = "0A"; (1..(10**2)).each do |m|; puts a; a.succ!; end